# How to optimize 3D Object in A-Frame to load faster

Tags: 3d, aframe, 3dsmax

So I have a couple of 3D objects that I want to load in my A-Frame But the problem Is The size of the 3d Object is so big. The estimation of the 3d object can up to 500mb. Okay, first thing first I'm not really used to 3d object. Is there any way to compress my 3d Object? because the scale I use for my 3D Object in A-Frame actually just 0.012,  Because now it takes forever to load my A-Frame scene and it pretty laggy And for now, I use OBJ + MTL and texture for my 3D Object and the 3D Object is created from 3dsmax. The guy who created the 3D Object says that the vertex used is already Optimized and can't make it smaller (This part I can't really confirm it, because that guy is not from our team). Do you have a suggestion to make the performance better? Maybe a suggestion for the A-Frame or for the 3D Object so I can forward it to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to know if your model has a particular issue that could make it less efficient without looking at the data.

However, the usual process is to reduce the number of polygon of your 3d model. Retopology is the process of converting high-resolution models into something much smaller. You might want to join the 3ds Max beta as they are currently working on an automatic retopology tool that might be helpful to you. https://youtu.be/STeG47Sy03E?t=152

Another thing you could look at is reducing the size of your texture file(s) that are used in your 3d model.

Comment: As a follow up, Autodesk has released the retopology component for 3ds Max on December 2 2020.  You can now use it without having to join the 3ds Max beta.